# How to report a malicious site to Google, Microsoft, Mozilla, etc. so that they will warn users

Tags: security, internet, anti-virus

I completed a project a year ago. Now a few modification were needed.

While trying to test the site, there was an `index.html` file with a malicious script which had an iframe to another site's jar file. Kaspersky antivirus blocked it.

I browsed via ftp to find the file and I deleted it. I also disabled directory listing.

Maybe the ftp details of the site owner would have been hacked.

I want to report this site to Google, Microsoft, Mozilla, and other antivirus providers. How do I do that?

I hope kaspersky would have updated it in their database, but I still want to explicitly report this.

Here is the popup kaspersky showed:

[image]

Comment: In addition to the steps I listed below for reporting the website in question, I would also make sure to change all FTP account passwords for your site, and if you're running any sort of CMS, update it to the later version in case a security vulnerability let attackers into your site.

Comment: Yes. we have requested our client to do that.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

- Report *any malicious pages* to Google on the **[Google malware reporting page](http://www.google.com/safebrowsing/report_badware/)**. This data gets put into the **Google SafeBrowsing Database**, which both Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox, as well as some other browsers, use to determine if a site is compromised.
- Report spam or malware *in Google search results* using **[Google Webmaster Tools spam report](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/spamreport?hl=en)**.
- <strike>Report *any malicious pages* to **[badwarebusters.org](https://badwarebusters.org/community/submit)**. Data from this organization is used by a variety of internet companies, including Google, PayPal, Mozilla, and MySpace.</strike> (badwarebusters.org shut down in Feb 2015)
- Microsoft uses their own SmartScreen Filter to determine in IE if a page is compromised. You can report pages to them by clicking on the Safety menu under tools, and clicking on `Report Unsafe Website`.
- Report phishing attempts to **DynDNS [PhishTank](http://www.phishtank.com/)**. Their database is used by many antivirus companies, browsers, and other software.

Comment: Another organisation, which for what I've heard is used by Google too, and hence will probably be synchronised with the other services: http://www.phishtank.com

Comment: @Arjan, thanks for the tip. I added phishtank to the list.

Comment: Nice answer, but I cannot upvote twice ;-)

Comment: badwarebusters.org shut down in February 2015.