# Adding a website to a global blacklist

Tags: firefox, internet-explorer, phishing, blacklist

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to report a malicious site to Google, Microsoft, Mozilla, etc. so that they will warn users](https://superuser.com/questions/224795/how-to-report-a-malicious-site-to-google-microsoft-mozilla-etc-so-that-they)

I recently received a phishing scam in my email.  I recognized it immediately, but I like to live dangerously, so I clicked the link.  (Of course I didn't enter my user name and password.)

I use Firefox, and noticed that the site was not flagged as malicious or a potential phishing website.  To help others on the Internet, I'd like to submit the site to be blacklisted.

What is the process of getting a website recognized as malicious by Firefox?  Is it possible to blacklist it in IE?  Is there a blacklist authority that should be made aware of this new phishing site?

Comment: I like to check phishing sites out too, but I do it from a linux browser to be safer.

Comment: @Indrek You're right.  Vote to close.