# Why does Google chrome redirect me to a weird website?

Tags: google-chrome, malware

I was typing in facaebook.com on the address box, Google Chrome redirected me to different websites like this one

```
http://askupdate.amazingstaff4downloadtoday.stream/?pcl=IB3C2ISWhMn8YxJRzQUPnrThW4k6WNZYJEWuW8lvgNYv1-ZGtMVlqFFYpopG4-tN41ZSO1cHNTnI_tjdo2iQrw..&cid=CAAoAAyLXlTsAD&subid=964972912&v_id=ps0AcEVvGLWuycwShGh0StcDsfYBcuoMZy5q0bWZ_4Y.
```

and this one

```
http://freechecknow.amazingstaff4downloadtoday.stream/?pcl=IB3C2ISWhMn8YxJRzQUPnrThW4k6WNZYJEWuW8lvgNYv1-ZGtMVlqFFYpopG4-tN41ZSO1cHNTnI_tjdo2iQrw..&cid=CAAoAAyLXlUPfA&subid=964972912&v_id=xTTW3Sja5tf7XUNPZzkUd2V64sTg-Ycx7mRg-icNMLg.
```

Has my browser been hijacked? If so, how can I delete the malware?

Comment: Try running Chrome without your extensions. There could be one that's had a brain transplant, or one that's simply malicious.

Comment: Possible duplicate [here](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it looks that your browser been hijacked. You can easily fix these issues. You need to reset all of your browsers' settings, clean unwanted, suspicious extensions of and probably scan your system with some kind of anti-virus or anti-malware tool. These programs can find possible threats since browser hijacker come silently it might carry other stuff around. Resetting, cleaning might help even if your system is affected by adware. These PUPs also cause redirects. Anti-malware detects all intruders.

Comment: I had issue with tripledeliveryinstance. This helped me realize the problem - https://securedstatus.com/how-to-remove-tripledeliveryinstance-com/

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem too. I fixed it by uninstalling Pop Up Blocker extension. My address bar works just fine now :)

Comment: Was that the entire, complete name of the extension you removed?

Answer (score -1):

Alternatively, if you did in fact type in the url `facaebook.com` precisely, then it may just be this is what that website does.

Going to `facaebook.com` now redirects me to a malicious site. 
It seems to just redirect almost at random to other sites, potentially the ones that you ended up on.

So it is possible that you don't actually have any malware on your computer (though checking is always good) but just type the `facebook.com` incorrectly.

The fix is just to close the window and possibly report it.
You can report sites like this as shown in this post: https://superuser.com/a/224803/

I would recommend reporting it Mozillas/Google database which can be found here:
http://www.google.com/safebrowsing/report_badware/